# Retornar somente a hora no Select

Tags: oracle11g

Como faço para retornar somente a hora no Select?

Declarei a hora como `TIMESTAMP`, neste caso retornou a data e a hora, mas quero que retorne somente a hora. Então declarei somente `DATE` e agora não vem a hora, vem somente a data.

o código esta assim:

```
INSERT INTO locacao
  (loc_codigo
  ,cli_codigo
  ,vei_placa
  ,datalocacao
  ,horalocacao
  ,datadevolucao
  ,horadevolucao
  ,qtddias
  ,valordia
  ,finalizado)
VALUES
  (01
  ,1
  ,'ABC1234'
  ,(TO_DATE('01/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'))
  ,TO_DATE('08:30','HH24:MI:SS')
  ,TO_DATE('06/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ,TO_DATE('07:00','HH24:MI:SS')
  ,5
  ,100.00
  ,1);
```

Comment: Elaine, tem como postar a declaração da tabela?

Comment: ...
                      DataLocacao   DATE            NOT NULL,
                      HoraLocacao   DATE            NOT NULL,
                      DataDevolucao DATE,
                      HoraDevolucao DATE,
                      QtdDias       INTEGER ,        
                      ValorDia      NUMBER(8,2)     NOT NULL,
                      Finalizado    NUMBER(3) DEFAULT(0)   NOT NULL);

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(datahora,'HH24') AS HORA FROM tabela
```

Comment: Postei o código, como esta. Quando cololo o SELECT * FROM 'TABELA' ; Os dados da hora não vem, no lugar vem uma data.

Comment: Para funcionar o campo tem de ser do tipo TIMESTAMP. Você não pode selecionar a hora de um campo que não guarda a hora.

Comment: ótimo, boa dica. Muito obrigada Reginaldo.

Answer (score 1):

Elaine, acredito que não precisa criar o campo de `horalocacao` e `horadevolucao`, pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

Com base nos dados que passou, a criação tabela ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCACAO (loc_codigo number(11)
  ,cli_codigo number(11)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,vei_placa varchar(7)  NOT NULL
  ,datalocacao date  NOT NULL
  ,datadevolucao date  NOT NULL
  ,qtddias integer(11)
  ,valordia number(8,2)  NOT NULL
  ,finalizado number(3) DEFAULT(0) NOT NULL
  );
```

A Inclusão:

```
INSERT INTO locacao
  (loc_codigo
  ,cli_codigo
  ,vei_placa
  ,datalocacao
  ,datadevolucao
  ,qtddias
  ,valordia
  ,finalizado)
VALUES
  (01
  ,1
  ,'ABC1234'
  ,TO_DATE('01/02/2016 08:30:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  ,TO_DATE('06/02/2016 07:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  ,5
  ,100.00
  ,1);
```

E a consulta, caso queria os campos de `horalocacao` e `horadevolucao` convertido para horas, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT loc_codigo
      ,cli_codigo
      ,vei_placa
      ,TO_CHAR(datalocacao,'DD/MM/RRRR') datalocacao
      ,TO_CHAR(datalocacao,'HH24:MI:SS') horalocacao
      ,TO_CHAR(datadevolucao,'DD/MM/RRRR') datadevolucao
      ,TO_CHAR(datadevolucao,'HH24:MI:SS') horadevolucao
      ,qtddias
      ,valordia
      ,finalizado
  FROM locacao
```

Seria melhor essa solução, pois o `DATE` guarda os valores de date e hora, então não precisando criar os campos de `horalocacao` e `horadevolucao`, e caso queria exibir somente a hora ou data faz através da consulta.

Comment: ótimo. Muito obrigada! Farei assim!

Comment: Elaine, caso te atenda, marque ao lado (simbolo de certo), como aceita a resposta. :)

Comment: ótimo, fiz exatamente assim. Só mudando alguns tipos. E para o SELECT que eu queria usei tb este que vc indicou, mas também usei este. SELECT LOC_CODIGO,CLI_Codigo, VEI_Placa, TO_CHAR(DataLocacao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as DATALOC, TO_CHAR(DataLocacao, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS HORALOC, TO_CHAR(DataDevolucao, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AS DATADEV, TO_CHAR(DataDevolucao, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS HORDEV, QtdDias, ValorDia, Finalizado FROM LOCACAO;

Comment: Qualquer outra dúvida Elaine, so fazer uma pergunta que nos te ajudamos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') Hora,
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MM:SS') Completo
FROM dual;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cleber, irei ver esta solução. Muito obrigada.